# Android Sqlite Like operator with "OR" statements

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to check if a query is found in one of three columns.
However, the query is searched for only in the first column mentioned:

```
 string[] a = new string[1];
 a[0] = '%' + query + '%';

 var sqldb_query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE Col_1 LIKE ? OR Col_2 LIKE ? OR Col_3 LIKE ?";
 var sqldb_cursor = myDb.RawQuery(sqldb_query, a);
```

It finds only queries that are in Col_1, not in the others.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You have 3 `?` in your code but have one arg, didn't get query error ?

Comment: @Shayan No. Why is that a problem?

Comment: It's a problem because the second and third `LIKE` expressions are probably comparing columns against `NULL`, or some other value you don't want.

Comment: Duplicate of [Pass same parameters multiple times in SQLitecommand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527639/pass-same-parameters-multiple-times-in-sqlitecommand)

Comment: because each arg must be place in one `?`, so you must pass array size with `?` number length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never bind parameters for the second and third `LIKE` expressions in your query.  Edit: If you want to use the same `LIKE` expression several times, you still need to bind however many times you have placeholders.

```
string[] a = new string[3];
string likeString = '%' + query + '%';
a[0] = '%' + query + '%';
a[1] = '%' + query + '%';
a[2] = '%' + query + '%';

var sqldb_query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE Col_1 LIKE ? OR Col_2 LIKE ? OR Col_3 LIKE ?";
var sqldb_cursor = myDb.RawQuery(sqldb_query, a);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to check for each of the queries whether they appear in each column. Not only query 1 for column 1 etc.

Comment: Update your question and show us an actual raw SQLite query which you want to run.  I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: `each of the queries` ... there is only _one_ query here.

Comment: I want to check for instance if "apple" appears either in column 1 or in column 2 or in column 3

Comment: Then you already have this logic in your query.  What is your understanding of the query you wrote?

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood it. Thanks.

Comment: What if I have two words "apple banana", and I want to check whether "apple" AND "banana" appear somewhere in one of the columns? But not only if they are together. It will find it also if the column contains "apple pear orange banana".

Comment: Then use this: `WHERE (Col_1 LIKE '%apple%' OR Col_2 LIKE '%apple%' OR Col_3 LIKE '%apple%') AND (Col_1 LIKE '%banana%' OR Col_2 LIKE '%banana%' OR Col_3 LIKE '%banana%')`

Comment: Yes, you can, I only gave you raw SQL so it would be easier to understand.  Sadly, SQLite doesn't have very good regex/text search support.

Comment: And what would the array look like? Something like this: {"apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "banana"}?

Comment: Yes, that looks right, except that you left out the wildcards.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Works like a charm!